# Flatten XPath from XML into a Perl hash

Tags: xml, perl, recursion

Given an XPATH such as '//element_name' I want to pull the resulting structure, say:-

```
<element_name>
   <tag1>value1</tag1>
   <nested>
     <tag2>value2</tag2>
   </nested>
</element_name>
```

...and then flatten it into a hash:-

```
{ 'tag1' => 'value1',
  'tag2' => 'value2'
}
```

So, basically I go as deep as I can into the tree and when I cannot go any deeper I write to the hash.

The element values will always be unique. If for some reason they are not, I don't mind them overwriting the hash.

This clearly needs some recursion. But my question is which perl XML parser is the best to achieve this? Any pointers on code structure appreciated as well. The end result will be an SQL statement hence the uniqueness of tags. I cannot import the XML directly as some tags will need further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you know how to find the element_name elements, so I'll proceed from there.

---

You want the name and text content of the elements

1. that are descendants of *element_name* elements, and
2. that have no element children.

You can use the following XPath to find those nodes:

```
descendant::*[count(*)=0]
```

Alternative:

```
.//*[count(*)=0]
```

With XML::LibXML, the whole missing part would look like:

```
for my $tag_node ($element_node->findnodes('descendant::*[count(*)=0]')) {
    my $name = $tag_node->nodeName();
    my $text = $tag_node->textContent();
    $hash{$name} = $text;
}
```